# NoClassDefFoundError Constructor.newInstance

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I have a big project that has several classes running together. I'm not sure how I can post it on here but basically i'm running into this `NoClassDefFoundError`. I have like 20 Classes in this Java Program, pretty basic stuff for you guys its a ShoeStore and BookStore. I just don't get whats happening, and i'm unsure of how to post it all for someone to look through it and see what is going on because I am totally stumped. I have no idea why this is happening to me now I've never had this problem before.

Can anyone help me? I'm pretty sure you need to see the whole program just to know where i'm running into issues.

I apologize for not having the code here, but i'm just unsure of how to proceed as I think this effects the entire program and its classes

I have commented below on my situation. I've gone through all my classes and I don't see anything misnamed but I could be wrong, doesn't seem to help that other article for what i'm seeing.

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize TestAssignment1 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)" is what its saying to me " this is what i'm seeing

Comment: Does it mention which class? If it gives you a class name, check if the name is misspelled, and then search for the place in your code that uses the misspelling. (Just a guess off-the-cuff).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize TestAssignment1 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)" is what its saying to me

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just initialized the HashMap completely wrong and I didn't even notice. Thank you for your help guys, pretty impossible thing to figure out without the entire code